# jQuery Vs JavaScript accordion solution comparison (one is buggy, other one is not)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm learning JavaScript and jQuery and there is one question that bothers me a lot.

Using this code in the accordion:

```
var panel = this.nextElementSibling;

if (panel.style.maxHeight){
  panel.style.maxHeight = null;
} else {
  panel.style.maxHeight = panel.scrollHeight + "px";
}
```

Gives a perfect result, I can click many times and even using double-click in my mouse doesn't open the panel of the accordion. I think this case doesn't need the source code, you should see it in the code, however, I can't seem to understand.

This code is taken from https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_accordion.asp site.

Let's compare jQuery version now:

```
let panel = $(this).next();

if (parseInt(panel.css("max-height")) > 0) {
  panel.css("max-height", 0);
} else {
  panel.css("max-height", panel[0].scrollHeight);
}
```

What's the deal? jQuery version's working good when you click the accordion button once, however, it bugs when you click it many times fast, unlike the JS solution.

---

Video showing both cases, 1st one is JS, the second - jQuery.

1st - https://youtu.be/HpTLexLuPYk.

2nd - https://youtu.be/vWQlDHFqYxY.

Any ideas?

Comment: Anyone, please? :/

Comment: jQuery is slower because you generate the jQuery object and then have to use the wrappers.

Comment: And that's the answer? If, for example, the user's PC is potato from the 20s, will use JS still produce the same effect as now, using modern PC from the 21s?

Comment: It will, the operations are super simple and javascript is not slow as the internet wants to make you think. For example https://jsperf.com/javascript-toggle-performance/3 will show you how many operation per second a style/class change of a DOM element needs in your browser. For me (intel i7-8700k): style change 229,366 Operation/s and class change 1,709,408 and i really don't believe you can click that fast. Even my potato netbook (Intel 1.6GHz Atom N270) can performs with 4,000 Op/s and 37.000 Op/s

Comment: And for jQuery, this will show you how much worse jQuery is when querying a DOM element and then changing the style  https://jsperf.com/style-versus-jquery-css Also just as a reminder you can keep a reference to a element instead of searching it on every click, which is much MUCH better for the performance.

Comment: @HansKoch Yes, I could do the reference, however, is it possible to use it if I'm dealing with `this` keyword?

Comment: You can always keep the `this` via `var that = this`. But for your click example the even itself holds a reference to the clicked element `var target = event.target || event.srcElement`